# Probability distribution of new data given old data

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, frequentist

Say we observe data $D$, which comes from a probability distribution $P[D|\theta]$, where $\theta$ are the unknown model parameters. Given this information, what is the probability distribution of the future data $D'$?

Further questions:

1. Does this aim have a specific name in the literature?
2. Can this question be addressed using Frequentist statistics?
3. For Bayesian statistics I came up with the following procedure

   - Find posterior $P[\theta|D]$
   - Find $P[D'|D] = \int_\theta P[D'|\theta]P[\theta|D]d\theta$

Does this approach make sense? Is this what people typically do?

Comment: You found the posterior predictive distribution.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Thanks, that answers Q3 and Q1

Comment: Wasn't trained in the frequentist arts, but I think their notion is to find $\theta_{\text{MLE}}$ based on $D$, then compute the probability of $D'$ under that model.

Comment: Yeah, that's the obvious solution, but it is of course wrong. Surely you don't need the notion of prior to comprehend the fact that picking the MLE parameter for prediction ignores the uncertainty of MLE. I was wondering if one can do something similar to predictive prior distribution, but instead integrate over the parameter estimator distribution

Comment: Once you start integrating out parameters, you've entered Bayesian-land. Is this question based on some external requirement  to operate in a frequentist framework, or is it curiosity?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Still, this question is very important and quite common in practice. Given the number of followers of frequentist school I would guess that they must have come up with some way to deal with it. I don't really care too much, just curious

Comment: @Arya McCarthy: Well, we have frequentist  [tag:prediction-interval]s, see this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473512/prediction-intervals-for-a-single-random-variable. They take into account parameter uncertainlt without integrating it out in Bayesian fashion, but typically using a [tag:pivot] in the same way as in constructing a confidence interval. I will try to write an answer!

Comment: I believe https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26702 might answer #2.  For examples, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17773, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265856, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14515, *etc.*  (found with a search for "prediction interval").